# Arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions in the random set of values of a non-lacunary sequence.

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{logn}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-P(X_n=1), for $ $n\geq2$.

Show that almost surely the set $ S(ω)=\{{n\in\mathbb{N }:X_n(ω)=1}\} $ is a set of recurrence.

What I have shown is that a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a set of recurrence if it contains arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions starting from 0, i.e. for every k $\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists some n $\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the arithmetic progression {n,2n,...,kn} belongs to the subset.

So, all I have to prove is that S(ω) almost surely contains arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions starting from zero, that is $P(\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}${$X_n(ω)=1,X_{2n}(ω)=1,...,X_{kn}(ω)=1\})=1$.

Now, this holds if for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $$P(\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\{X_n(ω)=1,X_{2n}(ω)=1,...,X_{kn}(ω)=1\})=1$$
The independence implies that P({$X_n(ω)=1,X_{2n}(ω)=1,...,X_{kn}(ω)=1$}$)=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{log(in)}$

We can also consider the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(ω)X_{2n}...X_{kn}(ω) $ which is the number of k-term arithmetic progressions contained in S(ω). Then we have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(ω)X_{2n}(ω)...X_{kn}(ω) >0$ almost surely.

What we know is that the expected value
$$\mathbf{E}[\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(ω)X_{2n}(ω)•••X_{kn}(ω)]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{E}[X_n(ω)X_{2n}(ω)•••X_{kn}(ω)]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{log(in)}=\infty$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Alright, I have solved it. If someone shows interest I may as well upload the solution. (It uses the above conclusion and Chebyshev's inequality)

Comment: It's actually trivial. Look at the events $1 \in S(\omega), 2,3 \in S(\omega), 4,5,6 \in S(\omega), 7,8,9,10 \in S(\omega), \dots$. These events are independent and the sum of their probabilities is infinite, so Borel-Cantelli means almost surely infinitely many of them happen.